# Multi regression of unbalanced data

Tags: r

I am trying to analyze this data; Students test scores on general education were sampled across a states school districts and schools. Class size (a dummy coded variable indicating smaller to very larger class sizes) was also collected. Determine the impact of class size on general education scores. Be sure to perform a analysis and provide a full summary.

I tried to use lmer, but figured that data is not a balanced design, Can someone advise me via R studio?

I checked the skewness of educationscore and solved the skewness by log（educationscore+0.2)

Dataset is an Excel file, I can't upload, so I have to post the file link here.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_ovhvrrFVNV2gP8c5vrg1FZ8C9x9NqCT

Answer (score 0):

if the linear model conditions are not complied, doesnt imply the model wont predict,it just means that the pvalues might be wrong.

Just split on train and test and check if the test group is well predicted.